# How to use generics within same class that generic was made?

Tags: c#, generics

For example I have this code:

```
public abstract class CubeClient <T> where T : CubeConnection<T> {...}
```

And I want to extend it using the CubeConnection while CubeConnection having CubeClient

```
public class CubeConnection<T> where T : CubeClient<T> { ... }
```

But problem that I am receiving is:

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method `CubeClient<T>`. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to `CubeNetwork.CubeConnection<T>`.   CubeNetwork

What should I do ?

Comment: `T` also needs to be `CubeConnection<T>` to satisfy the constraint on `T` from `CubeClient` e.g. `public class CubeConnection<T> where T : CubeClient<T>, CubeConnection<T>`. Since these are both classes with no inheritence relationship this constraint cannot be satisfied.

Comment: How could this work?  You're saying that the parameter for `CubeClient` must be a `CubeConnection` and that the parameter for `CubeConnection` must be a `CubeClient`. It's circular.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You have a circular dependency. `CubeClient<T> where T : CubeConnection<T>` and vice versa is not going to work. Please create a [mcve] and explain how you want to use this code.

Comment: So basically circular ain't going to work. I will find another way. Thank you all.

Comment: thats probably a [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Maybe you could create an Interface for T. Then you could define T as [...] `where T : IMyTType` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not help, but this compiles and has nearly the same constraints:

```
public abstract class CubeClient<T1, T2>
    where T1 : CubeClient<T1, T2>
    where T2 : CubeConnection<T1, T2>
{
}

public abstract class CubeConnection<T1, T2>
    where T1 : CubeClient<T1, T2>
    where T2 : CubeConnection<T1, T2>
{
}
```

You can then go on to define, for example, these concrete classes:

```
public class FooClient : CubeClient<FooClient, BarConnection>
{
}

public class BarConnection : CubeConnection<FooClient, BarConnection>
{
}
```

Again, these compile fine.

This is basically a [**Gang Of Four** "Bridge Pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern), done with generics.

But this does sound like you're trying to solve a different problem with this as the solution - and this has now become your "problem by proxy". In other words, an X-Y problem. Can you describe the underlying issue?

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you.